# Merging rows based on multiple variables

Tags: r

Working with a dataset that looks like this:

```
UserID       PartnerID  Happiness  Result
   1             2              30        1 
   2             1              20        1
```

As you can see this is repetitive. I'd like to take those two rows above and merge them into a single row. I have searched around but haven't found a solution that would work here. My ideal output would be this:

```
  UserID    PartnerID Happiness1   Happiness2    Result
     1          2            30         20         1
```

Comment: What is your logic for merging the `Success` and `Partner` columns?

Comment: Basically assume partner 1 and 2 meet and they strike up a deal. Im working on a dataset looking at negotiations and whether or not the outcome was successful or not. Instead of having duplicate rows for failed and successful negotiations, i want to merge them into one with the other data specific to each partner in that row to test prediction algorithms.

Comment: Shouldn't the ID of both partners be included in the merged row? If not, why 2 is included and not 1?

Comment: @989 yep thats the first column (ID)

Comment: Thus, to avoid confusion, I think better to add another negotiation and the resultant merged row to your example data. Its not clear whether the first column is the ID or the `Partner` column.

Comment: @989 agreed that it was confusing. Hopefully the edits make it clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, suppose your data is (I just added more toy data for the sake of clarity):

```
> df

# UserID PartnerID Happiness Result
  # 1         4        30      1
  # 2         3        20      0
  # 3         2        10      0
  # 4         1        15      1
  #10         13       20      1
  # 13        10       25      1
  # 5         6        10      0
  # 11        12       10      1
  # 6         5        10      0
  # 12        11       15      1
```

Then this:

```
dups <- duplicated(t(apply(df[,c(1,2)],1,sort)))
cbind(df[, c(1,3)], df[match(df$UserID,df$PartnerID), c(1,3,4)])[dups,]
```

Will give you your desired output:

```
  # UserID Happiness UserID Happiness Result
#      3        10        2          20      0
#      4        15        1          30      1
#     13        25       10          20      1
#      6        10        5          10      0
#     12        15       11          10      1
```

Comment: So this isn't working for me. I potentially am changing the code to fit my dataset incorrectly. Can you explain the last line of code? Unsure what the numbers in  the c() refer to. I added the numbers of the columns I want in the new df, but I dont get the numbers for BOTH users. Additionally, when I run this code I am still getting two entries for each match. L

Comment: @leeum If so, the structure of your real data differs from what you provided here. You see that based on given data, it works well. Those numbers in `c()` tell us which columns to choose after merging. You can simply ignore them to see all columns.

Comment: Are the `UserID` and `PartnerID` positioned in the first two columns (respectively) in your real data?

Comment: Just got this to work. I think its helpful to run the code without the `c()` first so that you can pick and choose the columns you want in the end. Exactly what I needed for this problem though.

Comment: @leeum OK nice. Yes, I told you those numbers are just columns indices and you simply can ignore them.

Comment: when I run this updated code, the second group of data that contains the partner's information is copied several times. So I get partner A's data, and then Partner B's data I get, but I get several rows of it below.

Comment: I believe an issue with the code above is `cbind(df[, c(1,3)], df[match(df$UserID,df$PartnerID), c(1,3,4)])[dups,]` should read `cbind(df[, c(1,3)], df[match(df$PartnerID,df$UserID), c(1,3,4)])[dups,]`

Comment: @leeum As I said, it seems your real data is a bit different from what you posted in your question. This solution works perfectly with the defined problem in your question. Just run the code on this data frame and see every thing is fine.

Comment: `df=structure(list(UserID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 13L, 5L, 11L, 
6L, 12L), PartnerID = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 10L, 6L, 12L, 5L, 
11L), Happiness = c(30L, 20L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
15L), Result = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("UserID", 
"PartnerID", "Happiness", "Result"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))`

Answer (score 2):

If you have no aversion to using packages, I would recommend you use `tidyverse` for this. The following piece of code should get your desired output:

```
#install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyverse")

library(tidyverse)


# Create a data.frame
dff <- structure(list(UserID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                      PartnerID = c(2,1, 4, 3, 6, 5), 
                      Happiness = c(30, 20, 40, 50, 30, 20), 
                      Result = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), 
                 .Names = c("UserID", "PartnerID", "Happiness","Result"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
                 class = "data.frame")


# UserID PartnerID Happiness Result
# 1      2         30        1     
# 2      1         20        1     
# 3      4         40        1     
# 4      3         50        1     
# 5      6         30        1     
# 6      5         20        1  


# Reshape the data.frame
dff %>% mutate(grouper = paste(UserID, 
                               PartnerID, 
                               sep = "")) %>%
  mutate(grouper = unlist(map(strsplit(grouper,""),
                              function(x) paste0(sort(x),
                                                 collapse="")))) %>%
  group_by(grouper) %>%
  mutate(Happiness = toString(Happiness)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::filter(!duplicated(grouper)) %>%
  separate(Happiness, into = c("Happiness1","Happiness2")) %>%
  select(-grouper)
```

This solution uses chained operations with the help of the `%>%` operator.

The idea here is to create a grouping column (called `grouper`) by first concatenating the UserID and PartnerID columns, and then `sorting` the characters in each row. At this point, the `grouper` column should contain the ID of the user and the ID of their partner in a sorted order. This means that both the user and their partner have the values in the `grouper` column. Therefore, you can go ahead and use the `group_by` function from `tidyverse` to group your data by the `grouper` column. Once you have been able to group the data, you can `mutate` the `Happiness` column to a string (that's what the `toString` function is doing). Then at this point you can `ungroup` and filter out the duplicates. Once the duplicates are taken out, you can `separate` the `Happiness` column into two different columns: `Happiness1` and `Happiness2`. Ultimately, you can drop the `grouper` column by using `select(-grouper)`.

That should yield:

```
# UserID PartnerID Happiness1 Happiness2 Result
# 1      2         30         20         1     
# 3      4         40         50         1     
# 5      6         30         20         1
```

I hope this helps.